# Powering 5 fans from 230V wall power

Tags: power-supply, power, fan-controller, power-converter

I need to power 4x40mm 2-pin (already owned) and 1x120mm fans (the 120 I still need to buy, so it can either be a 3 or 4-pin), from 230V wall power (EU socket).

I was thinking of using these components:

- 120mm 5V 3-pin fan: https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/1226679/noctua-nf-f12-5v-120mm/specificaties/
- Distribution board: https://www.megekko.nl/product/2503/945809/Interne-fancontrollers/DeLOCK-25218-Distribution-Board-6x-fan-5V-12V?s_o=1
- USB-A to molex 3.5 connector: https://www.megekko.nl/product/2503/945809/Interne-fancontrollers/DeLOCK-25218-Distribution-Board-6x-fan-5V-12V?s_o=1
- any generic 5V USB-A power brick (whichever)

Would this solution work? Is there anything that I am forgetting? Do you have any recommendation to change this?

Comment: There are adapters meant for running old external hard drives that go from wall power straight to molex, and they support the 12V wires too (which USB does not). I would look for one of those.

Comment: @Romen do you have a link to any of those? The ones I can find are all out of stock

Comment: Nvm, I found 1 site with them in stock: 
 - 34W: https://www.aquatuning.com/en/cases-hardware/power-supplies/z23-phobya-external-psu-230v-to-4pin-molex-34-watt-including-euro/uk-plug
 - 70W: https://www.aquatuning.com/en/cases-hardware/power-supplies/z23-phobya-external-psu-230v-to-4pin-molex-70w-including-euro/uk-plug

And they also have fan splitters

Answer (score 1):

I went with the following:

- molex -> 9x 3-pin fan splitter: https://www.aquatuning.com/en/cable/fan-cable-and-adapter/lk-phobya-4pin-molex-to-9x-3pin-fan-splitter-pcb
- external PSU 230V -> molex: https://www.aquatuning.com/en/cases-hardware/power-supplies/z23-phobya-external-psu-230v-to-4pin-molex-34-watt-including-euro/uk-plug
- BeQuiet Silent Wings 3 120mm: https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/448653/be-quiet-silent-wings-3-120mm/specificaties/

Comment: This was partially successful. The 120mm fan works perfectly with this solution, but my 2-pin 40mm fans didn't want to turn on, with or without the 120mm plugged in.

Comment: I have no other easy way to test if the fans are just bad or if there was something wrong with the connection. The molex power supply did seem to be active when the fan was plugged in.

Comment: I might check if I can hook up a 5V usb power brick to the leads to see if the fan works at all. If that doesn't work, I'll assume that the fans are dead.